# Given x, How can I find all the sets of four numbers that add upto x

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, numbers

I know how find a set of two numbers. I can sort all the numbers from 0 to X-1. Put a pointer P1 at 0 and P2 at X-1 and for every step, increase the P1 by 1 and decrease P2 by 1. 
How do I start to find all the sets of 4 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

One (of many) easy solutions: A recursive function which generates one number and uses another call with modified x for the next. Pseudocode:

```
generate(x, digits, current[])
{
    if digits < 1
        print all current´s in one (single) line
        return
    for every i from 0 to x
        add i as new element to current
        generate (x - i, digits - 1, current)
        remove the last element of current again
}
```

current is some list, array etc., empty when calling the first time.
x is the number, and digits eg. 4 in the first call.

Comment: is that brute force all combinations?

Comment: @shole Yes, it is. But if you want *all* combinations (ie. print each of them or something like that), there is no other way than generating *all* combinations. (If someone doesn´t need the values, just the amount, or values fulfilling some cirteria etc., there are better ways.)